# Using the res:// protocol with System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use a resource (html file) located in a dll. With WinForms WebBrowser, when I navigate to the file, nothing happens, while with included AxSHDocVw.dll and SHDocVw.dll and AxWebBrowser, it works. Is the WinForms WebBrowser control somehow restricted or something? Can I make it to run res://?

Comment: What's the exact URL you're trying to use?

Answer (score 2):

See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672462/1413201.

The basic gist is there are two types of resources in code files.  You need to include a C style resource script to use the res protocol.  Navigation errors are probably turned off in the `WebBrowser` control and therefore you don't see an error.

You can use the res protocol with IE to test if the resource is actually in the file and a C style resource editor just to double double check.

Answer (score 1):

What I would assume, is that for security reasons, WinForms' WebBrowser control doesn't handle res:// links. It would make it very easy for someone to access resources which are contained within your DLLs which you may not want accessed.

If you want to implement the functionality yourself, then I'd recommend looking at the Assembly class and its use. It shouldn't be hard to parse a res:/// into your DLL path, load the assembly, search for the given resource and return that for the WebBrowser control.