# C++ Get file content from the DLL resource

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, webbrowser-control

I am working on my c++ application to view the html content in the webbrowser control. I have stored the .htm file in the dll "My Resources Files" and I would like to get access to it.

When I tried this:

```
webBrowser1->Navigate("res://test1.dll/frontpage.html");
```

It will not display the content in the webbrowser so I have also tried this:

```
webBrowser1->Navigate(System::Diagnostics::Process::Start(System::Environment::CurrentDirectory + "test1.dll\frontpage.htm"));
```

It did the same things and I am not sure why.

What I am trying to achieve is I want to get access to the test1.dll and get the frontpage.html file to output them in the webbrowser control.

Can you please show me an example how i can get access to the dll to fetch the html file and output them in the webbrowser control?

**EDIT: Here is the screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Related/dupe: [Using the res:// protocol with System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827792/), and [MS WebBrowser + Embedded HTML Resource + res:// Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254605/) You did not provide any details about how you setup your resource, but I'm betting you did not set it up correctly for the way the WebBrowser is looking for it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please see the screenshot that I have updated in my question. I hope this is the info you are asking for how I set it up?

Comment: Did you verify that the HTML file is actually being stored in the DLL's resources using the `RT_HTML` resource type, and with the filename as the resource identifier?

Comment: Yes I did but I realised that I have to store the html file in the DLL resources so I have stored it. So how I can get the id for the resource name and get the id for the html file?