# VLC ActiveX in a local webpage with WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, browser, activex, vlc

So I try to get working **VLC ActiveX v.2**  under **WPF WebBrowser control** and I load it locally.

And VLC ActiveX is not working...

**C#**

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "index.html");

 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
 {
     String url = sr.ReadToEnd();
     wb.NavigateToString(url);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <object width="720" height="408" id='vlc1_IE' events="True" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">
        <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
            width="720" height="408"
            id="vlc1">
        </embed>
        <param name="src" value="http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-52qL9xLP.mp4" />
        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
        <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

***Please note if I load it remotely it is working fine!***

Also I have tried to use index.html like an embedded resource.

So I have used

```
Stream docStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WpfApplication12.index.html");
wb.NavigateToStream(docStream);
```

Is it possible to do? Is WPF WebBrowser control very limited to execute local web page with ActiveX?

Any clue?

P.S. I've tried to do the same with WInForm WebBrowser control  - no joy...

P.S.#2 I've tried this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3919/Using-the-WebBrowser-control-simplified and the same HTML with VLC ActiveX is working fine there.
But it is done in C++ and I dont know it at all... :(

P.S. #3 I've just tried together MS Media Player and VLC ActiveX and MS Media Player is working fine!

```
  <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
            width="720" height="408"
            id="vlc1">
        </embed>

    <object classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
        <param name="URL" value="example.wmv" >
        </object>
```

[image]

P.S.#4 Also I have tried to create VLC ActiveX control dynamically using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537508%28VS.85%29.aspx) example but no joy at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this comment:

> Please note if I load it remotely it is working fine!

Are you using Internet Explorer for this test?  If so, do you have any plugins?

I ask this question because the WebBrowser control (at least in WinForms) does **not** support plugins / add-ons.  Just because something works in your full-blown browser does not necessarily mean that it will work in the WebBrowser.  If you are using an ActiveX plugin for this VLC integration, this likely won't work in the WebBrowser control.

**EDIT in Response to Comment**

When you try this code (and note that I've changed your second line slightly):

```
Stream docStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WpfApplication12.index.html");
wb.NavigateToStream(docStream);
```

...are you saying that it doesn't load the HTML **at all**?  Or does it load, but your video (VLC) control doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for the input, bro! It is a problem because I load a html file locally only and it happens with WinForm/WPF Browser controls. If I put html to IIS and point WPF WebBrowser control to REMOTE html it is working fine. Also as I said VS C++ project handles good this local file. (Well  I dont know how to convert C++ exe projext to DLL to host it under WPF project). And yes, there is no any IE plugins i have installed.

Comment: Also I have tried to play with IE Security options but it doesn't help.