# Loading .html, with css references, file Embedded In The Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

Well in my windows forms application i have a simple web browser which is supposed to run a `.html` file containing a `css` styled registration form. It is running very well when loading the page remotely using `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com/mypage.html");`; However, When i tried to embed the `.html` file [along with the `css` files required] in the resources by setting the `Building Action` to `Embedded Resource`, the `webBrowser` only navigates to the `.html` file while not detecting the `css` files, which result in a creepy page look.

Here are the codes i have tried so far.

The `.html` file  :

```
  <link href="lang/en/compact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="lang/en/lang.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="img/basics.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How i get the `.html` file from the `Embedded Resources` :

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                   .GetManifestResourceStream("DummyBrowserFormImprovements.HTML." + "mypage.html"))
    if (stream != null)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            dummyBrowser1.DocumentText = result;
        }
```

Unfortunately, The above approach only loads the `.html` file without recognizing the `css` files referenced in it; Hence, any detailed answer about how to embed a `.html` file that uses `js, css` external files in windows forms and how to load it into a `webBrowser` would be very **appreciated**. I hope i was clear in representing my problem and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because the other files are still embedded in your application. Where is the browser going to find them?

You could write all the required embedded files to temporary directory, and have your web browser load the .html page from there. Once the html page is loaded it should be able to find your other resources since they will be in the same directory (or whatever structure you make).

Basically I am saying that you could extract all your files into a temp directory structure like:

```
C:\mytempsite\mypage.html
C:\mytempsite\lang\en\compact.css
C:\mytempsite\lang\en\lang.css
C:\mytempsite\img\basics.css
```

Then you can set the web browser to [navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate.aspx) to "C:\mytempsite\mypage.html"

As long as you can navigate to this directly without your application, and the page loads correctly, then this should work from your application when it navigates there. Just make sure mypage.html has well formed html and is a complete page.

Comment: This is not working i have tried this the browser the webBrowser.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\mypage.html"); [With all the needed resources] it also can't load them...'

Comment: Is there any other way to directly run it from the resources without having to extract it ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, maybe someone else can think of away, but logically, I do not understand how the web browser control could find the css files if they are still embedded in your application.  


The only other way I could think to do that is to have all your css and other files as inline code. Then you only have one file and could set your web browser DocumentText to be the text of that one file.

Comment: There might be a way so i detect when the browser requests the css file then i respond to the browser with the embedded resource file.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254605/ms-webbrowser-embedded-html-resource-res-protocol it seems to have a lot of information about using the res:// protocol This might be what you need.