# Display PDF from a stream in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, pdf, webbrowser-control

How can I display a PDF document from a `MemoryStream` within a `WebBrowser` control?

I've searched around and found I can simply navigate to a PDF file using:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\Temp\ExportedPDF.pdf");
```

However I want to avoid saving the file anywhere, but I'm currently leaning towards using `IsolatedStorage` simply because I can't find any other method to get the stream into the browser control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a C# WebBrowser control to show jpeg files (raw)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290035/how-do-i-get-a-c-webbrowser-control-to-show-jpeg-files-raw)

Comment: I'll give that a go. Will take some time to implement but it looks promising.

Comment: Made some major progress, but there's an error with the code. See the question I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062642/feeding-pdf-through-iinternetsession-to-webbrowser-control-error