# Opening a PDF file which is a resource file embedded within a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, webbrowser-control, .net-4.5

I am trying to open a PDF file which is a resource file embedded within my WPF application.
The resource file is marked as a Resource for build action and also as do not copy. I am doing below without success. I am not able to build the Uri based on the embedded resource file:

```
        System.Windows.Controls.Frame frame = new System.Windows.Controls.Frame();
        System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser();
        browser.Unloaded += Browser_Unloaded;
        Uri myUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myApp;component/Resources/myPDFFile.pdf", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        browser.Navigate(myUri);
        frame.Content = browser;
```

And this is my method when PDF is unloaded:

```
    private void Browser_Unloaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        browser = frame.Content as System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser;
        browser.Dispose();
        frame.Content = null;
    }
```

Instead of a resource file embedded within the application, if I put the PDF somewhere in the disk and I specify the absolute path as "C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\myPDFFile.pdf", then it works but I want the PDF file to be embedded within the application as a resource file and be able to open it.

It looks like the URI I have built is not correct, sure is failing pack://application:,,,/myApp;component/Resources/myPDFFile.pdf but I am not able to see why.

Comment: You have 2 separate issues and should consider making them 2 separate questions.  1. How to handle the unloaded event, and 2. How to open the embedded resource. A potential responder might have an answer to one but not the other and the StackOverflow system doesn't work that way.  This question lacks focus.

Comment: @Tarazed updated with only one question.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control doesn't support pack URIs. You may be able to create a stream to display it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038043/display-pdf-from-a-stream-in-a-webbrowser-control. Or create a local temporary file from the stream.

Comment: Resource file of configuring file as an MSBuild Resource item and compile it into the assembly. WPF supports the construction of pack URIs that identify resource files that are compiled into a local assembly, or into an assembly referenced from a local assembly. But why don't you just in  introduce the corresponding resource files in xaml? Also could you tell me what controls you are  using to display the pdf?