# bind an image in c# using byte array

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

```cs
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            if (ext == ".png" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".PNG" || ext == ".JPG" || ext == ".JPEG" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".GIF")
            {

                Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +base64String ;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('unsupported format of photo file');</script>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219694/how-can-i-show-an-image-in-webbrowser-control-directly-from-memory

Comment: I just solve this problem....'string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +base64String;'

Comment: You should write that as an answer and accept it if the solution solves your problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +base64String ;
```

This code is working well ..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to display image with base64 string in an `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image`.

first, create a client JavaScript function to set `src` attribute of your `<img />` tag:

```
function setImageData(imageBase64) {
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = "data:image/png;base64," + imageBase64;
}
```

then, Invoke that method by

```
Response.Write("<script>setImageData("+ base64String +")</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create `ImageHandler` (inherited from IHttpHandler), register it in the web.config file, and modify your `Button2_Click` function:

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Image1.ImageUrl = "URL_TO_IMAGE_HANDLER.jpg";
    ...
}
```

You can read about http-handlers here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34084/Generic-Image-Handler-Using-IHttpHandler

This solution is much better than Base64 approach, it's also possible to implement caching support here

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv) Tutorial you can use byte array to get images

**UPDATE:** By the way you should use this function :

```
string imageDataParsed = imageData.Substring( imageData.IndexOf( ',' ) + 1 );
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String( imageDataParsed );
using ( var imageStream = new MemoryStream( imageBytes, false ) )
{
Bitmap image = new Bitmap( imageStream );
}
```

**Edit**
You can convert base64string to image by Image.FromStream. You will need to convert the base64string to stream first.

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64String);
MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms1);
```

Comment: Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);  in this section i am gettin g error--Error 6 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream

Comment: i just found out you are using base64 , look at my update answer

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this question..this is the updated code..

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                if (ext == ".png" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".PNG" || ext == ".JPG" || ext == ".JPEG" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".GIF")
                {

                    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('unsupported format of photo file');</script>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
```